# Parsing sentences (lines) into words

Tags: c, parsing

I need your opinions about how can I improve this code or if I have to improve this code.
It's reading an input file and parsing it into words then saving them into some dynamical structure like a linked list or tree.
I want to know if is is effective or if it could be more effective.

```
int maxSize = 256;
int currSize = maxSize;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int c;
char *line = (char*)malloc(maxSize);
char * pch; //

while((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
{
    line[i++] = c;

    if(c == '\n')
    {
        line[i] = '\0';
        pch = strtok (line," ,()?/|.!-\n:;^[]");
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            //Here will be adding procedure
            j++;
            pch = strtok (NULL, " ,()?/|.!-\n:;^[]");
        }

        line = (char*)malloc(maxSize);
        currSize = maxSize;
        i = 0;
    }

    if(i == currSize)
    {
        currSize = i + maxSize;
        line = (char*)realloc(line,currSize);
    }
}
```

Looking forward to your opinions. Thank you.

Comment: If your code executes as expected, this question may belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather then SO... But your code seems more likely incomplete as you are not storing `pch` anywere.

Comment: //Here will be adding procedure
Instead of that comment I have there adding procedure to store pch into linked list don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

**Read a line from file and store in array, then read the array from begining and tokenize it !!!**

Why do that if you can directly tokenize each word? P.S. If you have to process words of different lines differently, you can do that by separating `case '\n':`

```
    char *word=malloc(sizeof(char)*maxSize);
    int i=0;
    while(1){ 
        switch(c=fgetc(stdin)){
            case  ',': case '(': case ')': case '?': case '/': 
            case '|': case '.': case '!': case '-': case '\n':
            case ':': case ';': case '^': case '[': case']': case ' ':
                word[i]='\0';
                    //call your function here
                i=0;
                break;
            case EOF:
                word[i]='\0'
                if(i>0);
                    //call your function
                //file is read completely
                return;
            default:
                test[i++]=c;
        }
        if(i==maxSize); //reallocate
    }
```